# Plus one to mysql value problem

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem.

```
<?php
  if (isset($_GET['id']))
  {
    $_GET['id'] = intval($_GET['id']);

    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `banners` WHERE `id` = '" . $_GET['id'] . "'");
    if (mysql_num_rows($query))
    {
      $row = mysql_fetch_array($query);
      if ($row['views'] <= $row['ordered'])
      {
        if (empty($_GET['p']))
        {
          mysql_query("UPDATE `banners` SET `views` = `views` + 1 WHERE `id` = '" . $_GET['id'] . "'");
        }
        header('Content-type: '. $row['mime']);
        echo $row['image'];
      }
    }
  }
```

`script.php?id=1&p=`

The value `views` is changed to "plus two", and not plus one.

Now 14, after 16.

**EDIT:**

If I commented

```
header('Content-type: '. $row['mime']);
echo $row['image'];
```

It's good. Where is the problem?

**UPD 2:**

F5 -> Page loaded 2 times..

```
1: - Accept=text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8    
2: Accept=image/png,image/*;q=0.8,*/*;q=0.5
```

WTF?

Comment: This is injection-attack paradise. Prepare to be hacked. Also, it's 2011.

Comment: @Kerrek SB Though not ideal, won't `$_GET['id'] = intval($_GET['id']);
` prevent the injection attack?

Comment: Simply script is getting executed twice

Comment: @Kerrek SB it isn't injectable. intval(); saves it all

Comment: Replace `$_GET['id'] = intval($_GET['id']);` with `$id = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET'['id']);` and then use `'$id'` in your query. This is really bad code.

Comment: why mysql_real_escape_string? It doesn't make sense, if he wants intval, he wants intval and not a string

Comment: Oh, OK, apologies, I hadn't seen the reassignment of `$_GET['id']` -- OK, if you must... but all of this is terrible design -- check out prepared statements and PDO! :-)

Comment: @genesis, people always seem hellbent on reinventing `mysql_real_escape_string()` it's a bad idea, also MySQL does not allow id's with value 0, so there is no added values in using `intval`. using mysql_real_escape_string consistently makes it much easier to verify that your code is SQL-injection proof. This hides the logic in clever tricks not helpful at all.

Comment: but if $_GET['id'] is "hack123", intval() return 0. no worries, because I think there isn't 0 in DB.

Comment: @genesis: The query string is a **string**, no matter what you put in it. You should really treat it as a string. (But seriously do consider prepared statements for this thing.)

Answer (score 0):

As @Shakti Singh said, it's executed twice. If you have access to access.log on your server, look into it and you'll see that. If not, try to log access to your database.

Or, you have same code somewhere else and is executed, too